# how to edit/delete a row in grid view with no data keys ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, ado.net

I am using asp.net grid view to display data from an excel sheet. I can also add the data to this excel sheet using the grid view. The problem I am facing is in editing/updating and deleting records from the gridview/excel. When I update one row it updates every rows.

I do not have a primary key as it is excel sheet and there are only two columns name and value and both should be updatable

Here's what I have tried

```
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvExcelFile.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox TxtEditName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtEditName");
    TextBox TxtEditValue = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtEditValue");

    string enm = TxtEditName.Text;
    string evl = TxtEditValue.Text;
    gvExcelFile.EditIndex = -1;
    conn.Open();

    string editquery = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] set [Name]=? ,[Value]=?";
    OleDbCommand editcmd = new OleDbCommand(editquery, conn);
    editcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Name]", enm);
    editcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Value]", evl);
    editcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    gvbind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a column which is auto generated and use it as primary column

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No">
       <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: How will I use this column? Will I have to set it as a DataKey under properties of the gridview? How will I alter the db query? Could you please help as I am new to c#

Comment: I tried too many things around your suggestion but nothing turned up to be helpful. Please help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

I also tried doing this where in I directly update the cell in the excel from the grid view but it gave an error - "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in UPDATE statement." This also didn't work

```
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvExcelFile.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        TextBox TxtEditName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtEditName");
        TextBox TxtEditValue = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtEditValue");

        string enm = TxtEditName.Text;
        string evl = TxtEditValue.Text;
        int editindex = gvExcelFile.EditIndex;
        int currentindex = e.RowIndex;
         string editquery = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] set Sheet1$A"+currentindex+"=? ,Sheet1$B"+currentindex+"=?";
        gvExcelFile.EditIndex = -1;
        conn.Open();


        OleDbCommand editcmd = new OleDbCommand(editquery, conn);
        editcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sheet1$A"+currentindex, enm);
        editcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sheet1$B"+currentindex, evl);
        editcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        gvbind();
```

Answer (score 0):

tried using this ?

```
QueryString="UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [name]=<new value>, [value]=<new vlue> WHERE ( [name]=<old name> AND [value]=<old value>)
```

Comment: I tried using that but the problem is how to fetch the previous values. I have used labels to display values in grid view in a template field, when clicked on edit button a text box is displayed with the values and then you can change values and click on update. Here once you click on edit button the label disappears and so not able to fetch the old values.

Comment: maybe yu should declare two string variables nd assign the label's text to the variable when user clicks the update button.. then u still have the old values in those variables.. 
now you can use the variables in the update query

Comment: Yes I did the same but the thing is the moment user clicks on edit the label's disappear and the edit textbox are displayed and thus the old value are not accessible.